# Prompt the user to enter a password which matches a specific pattern

Tags: java

I have written some code but I cant seem to figure out how to get the exact number of characters, numbers, or symbols. I fixed my code a bit but it does not work and I'm not sure why.

My requirements are

> Write a Java program that prompts the user to enter a password that matches a specific pattern. Your program must approve the user's entry.. Here is the pattern, in this order:

```
-1 or more upper case letters
-two lower case letters
-1 or 2 digits
-zero or 1 upper case letters
-any two of this group @#$%^&
```

My Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestingCenter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int digit=0;
    int special=0;
    int upCount=0;
    int upCount2=0;
    int loCount=0;
    String password;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Enter Your Password:");
    password = scan.nextLine();

    for(int i =0;i<password.length();i++){
        char c = password.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isUpperCase(c)){
            upCount++;
    }
        if(Character.isLowerCase(c)){
            loCount++;
    }
        if(Character.isDigit(c)){
            digit++;
    }
        if(Character.isUpperCase(c)){
            upCount2++;
    }
        if(c>=33&&c<=46||c==64){
            special++;
     }
}
        if(special==2&&loCount==2&&upCount>=1&&(digit==1||digit==2)&&upCount2<=1){
        System.out.println(" Password is good:");
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: Which part of the instructions asked you to count anything?

Comment: "1 or 2 digits": does `digit>=1` really capture that? Same with "any two of this group @#$%^&"

Comment: "two lower case letters" should that read "two or more lowercase letters" or "exactly two lowercase letters"?

Comment: Exactly 2 lowercase letters

Comment: *1 or more upper case letters... zero or 1 upper case letters*... so, exactly 1 then?

Comment: My answer was wrong, and I have deleted it.  Read the @cricket_007's answer.  That is the correct one.  You cannot validate the password by simply counting characters. It is a **pattern** matching problem.   (However, I would note that the way the requirements are written is a bit odd.  They tricked me too.)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, **in this order** literally means in that given order.

If that's the case, you want regex. Forget counting characters.

- 1 or more upper case letters `[A-Z]+`
- two lower case letters `[a-z]{2}`
- 1 or 2 digits `\d{1,2}`
- zero or 1 upper case letters `[A-Z]?`
- any two of this group @#$%^& `[@#$%^&]{2}`

So,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(" Enter Your Password:");
String password = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(password.matches("[A-Z]+[a-z]{2}\\d{1,2}[A-Z]?[@#$%^&]{2}");
```

If that's not what your instructions meant, then check out your conditionals. Clearly not everything should be `>= 1`

Comment: I would think that "any two of this group @#$%^&" would imply no repeats

Comment: Repeats are not specified. Two of the same  character is considered "any two"

Comment: Perhaps, but it's not clear from the specifications what it means so I think michael needs to clarify this point.